# Why can't HP Web Jetadmin connect to a remote printer over OpenVPN?

Tags: openvpn, hp, printing

I'm using HP Web Jetadmin to monitor my printer fleet, and one of the features they advertise quite a bit is the ability to monitor printers at remote locations.

I have the server running at the office and have an HP Color LaserJet Pro M477fdw MFP at my home that I want to add to monitoring. I have a PiVPN server at home and I have created a profile for the WJA server at the office, which runs the OpenVPN Client. I have manually edited the profile to add these lines:

```
route-nopull
route 10.20.30.40 255.255.255.255
script-security 2
```

where `10.20.30.40` is the reserved LAN IP of my printer on my home network (I use an AirPort Extreme as my gateway which handles DHCP and NAT functions. The printer is connected via Ethernet and has a DHCP reserved IP address outside the dynamic range.). These lines cause only connections to this IP to be routed over the VPN -- everything else is routed to the LAN or the Internet as usual.

With this setup in place, I can connect to my printer's web server from a browser from my HP WJA server, and I can do an SNMP walk as well. There is no password set on the EWS or on the SNMP; however, I am still having issues monitoring the printer from HP WJA itself. The device discovers, but everything shows up as `<Unknown>`, including the printer name itself and other such basic details. The only thing that shows is that the paper trays are OK (not empty) -- I can't see cartridges though, or any other information about configuration or status. It is constantly in error state with `Device communication error` -- I have tried every menu item and context menu I can find to try to get more details on this error message, but I can't turn up anything that would point me to the specific issue?

Can anyone provide me with some guidance on this? For reference, I am running the client on the local server, which is running normal Windows 10 1709 with updates. Again, it is really odd as I can connect to the EWS and SNMP from the server. If you have some other means of monitoring remote devices, how do you do it? I have posted this in the Server Fault forum because I think it is more likely that people here will be familiar with HP WJA/what it is that I am trying to do; if it belongs more in Super User please let me know.

Thanks for the advance for the assistance.